# location listener

Tags: android, listener, latitude-longitude

I am using location listener to get long & lat for my android application.

I am working with the following code:

```
public Location getLastKnownLocation()
{
 Location location=null;
 try
 {
 // Get the location manager
 mLocMgr = (LocationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
 // List all providers:
 // List<String> providers = mLocMgr.getAllProviders();

 Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
 bestProvider = mLocMgr.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
 location = mLocMgr.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
 if(location==null)
 {
  Thread.sleep(5000);
  location=mLocMgr.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
 }
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
  Log.i("program", e.getMessage());
 }
 return location;
}

public Location updateCurrentLocation()
{
 Location mLoc=null;
 try
 {
 mLoc=getLastKnownLocation();
 mlocListener = new LocListener(); 
 mLocMgr.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 0, 0, mlocListener);
 mLoc=getLastKnownLocation();
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
  Log.e("program", e.getMessage());
 }
 return mLoc;
}
```

It is working absolutely fine. But facing the problem when we switched off the device and start it again. Then I am getting the location null.
However after starting the google map, it starts working again. 
So Could you please guys help me out on this because I don't want start the google map before starting my application. Thanking you for support!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `getLastKnownLocation` method is likely to fail when you power off and power on your device.

And, I see that, you are calling it before you subscribe to location update lister:

```
 mLoc=getLastKnownLocation();  //<<<<<<<<<<<<<
 mlocListener = new LocListener(); 
 mLocMgr.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 0, 0, mlocListener);
```

Why do you need to call `getLastKnownLocation()` ? It will not work immediately when you start your device.

When you are using Google map, it is gracefully trying to listen to location update. And, once it gets atleast one location update, then your `getLastKnownLocation` will start working.

I see that your architecture need re-thinking (if your method names are appropriate)

This should be called ONLY ONCE, in some appropriate location, when your app initiates.

```
mLocMgr.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 0, 0, mlocListener);
```

Then, do whatever update you need in `onLocationChanged(Location location)`

Comment: If this resolved your issue, then you should mark the answer as accepted. The tick symbol on left under the vote count

Answer (score 1):

Little Flyffy Location library:
http://code.google.com/p/little-fluffy-location-library/

Simple, fast, easy!

this library notify your location updates.